# Contains Test for a Constant Set

Tags: language-agnostic, code-generation, set, predicate

The problem statement:

Given a set of integers that is known in advance, **generate** code to test if a single integer is in the set. The domain of the testing function is the integers in some consecutive range.

---

Nothing in particular is known now about the range or the set to be tested. The range could be small or huge (but a solution can reject problems that are to big but higher limits are better). It could be that very few of the values in the allowed range are in the set or most of them are or anything in between. The set may be uniformly distributed or clustered. There may be large sections of only contained/not-contained values or there may be at least a few of each type of value in most swaths. (sort of like the assumption made about items to be sorted when analyzing sorting algorithms)

The objective is a procedure for generating effective code for running the test.

Partial solutions that come to mind include

- perfect hash function (costly for large sets)
- range tests: `foreach(b in ranges) if(b.l <= v && v <= b.h) return true;`
- trees/indexes (more costly than others in some cases)
- table lookup (costly for large sets)
- the inverse of any of these these (kodos to [Jason S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s))

It seems that an ideal solution would be able to pick what option is best or if none work well, use a tree to break down the full range into sections and then switch to other options for subsection that are better suited to them.

Topic(s) that might be useful include:

- [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)

---

Note: this is not homework. if it was issued as homework below the doctoral level the prof should be shot with a Nerf gun (if you don't get that then re-read the problem, it is very much non trivial)

Note: This is a problem that occurred to me a few days a go and I've been puzzling over it off and on. I have no direct use for this but thought it would be a cool problem to attack. The reason that I wan to generate the code is because generated code will be no slower than general code (it can be the same thing if needed) and might be faster in some/many cases.

I'm posting this question as much to clarify my thoughts as anything. If I can come up with any reasonable or cool solutions I plan on implementing them as a template meta program (the other reason for generated code)

some people have noted that the problem is very general. That is the point. I'm hoping to generate a system that would work an a very general domain: sets of integers in some range.

Comment: You've done a good job of explaining the problem except for why you want to do this, and why it needs to be generated code instead of a generic solution.  Can you fill in that info?

Comment: thanks for the clarification - now the question is not only ridiculously overgeneralized (handle 100B integers, handle 6 integers) but the explantation is condescending and offensive. Good job! Have a -1 for the effort, and a vote-to-close as 'not a real question' (because it is not a real problem).

Comment: @Steven: I think (but am not sure) that you are miss using the offensive tag. IIRC it is for spam, slander, porn and the like.

Comment: WTF? It's a valid question, covering several different problem domains (large sets, small sets, etc).

Comment: thanks for rewording the insulting section, offensive vote removed (I consider insulting the reader to be abuse/slander; let's keep it polite and friendly)

Comment: @[Jason S]: this question requests a code generator for an input problem with no constraints; it is therefore un-solvable. See 'answer'

Comment: p.s. I'd handle the non-code-generated approach first (a general algorithm), or at least several overlapping algorithms that handle different variants of the problem. Then if it looks like code-generation has a big win then use it. (otherwise it seems like a big effort)

Comment: @Steven: Odd, I left in the part I would expect to be the most offensive (re: "Nerf gun"). Why would you consider telling someone that they don't understand something to be offensive?

Comment: Why can't this just be a civilized discussion? It's a very open-ended problem, one that probably doesn't have a definite solution, but the OP is looking for some ideas on possible approaches.

Comment: I'm disappointed to see -1 votes, the problem I have with them in a case like this is that they attract other -1 votes, and repel people who might otherwise have made valid contributions to the question because they see "oh, it's one of those posts with negative points".

Comment: downvote removed to honor the OP's gracious responses. But I can't upvote it either, it's just not a real problem. Real problems have constraints. [and shooting CS professors with nerf guns is not offensive, it's mandatory]

Answer (score 1):

a [previous question on dictionary/spellchecking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405433/) had a number of responses that mentioned [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter); maybe that would help.

I would think that testing for large sets is going to be expensive no matter what.

Comment: Bloom filters are an extension to hashing. If I'm going that way, then I might as well do a minimum perfect hash or the like. It is a good thought and might be good for related questions.

Answer (score 1):

let's pretend, for a moment, that this is a real question:

- there are no limits on the size of the base set or the input set

this makes the "problem" unrealistic, underspecified, and un-solvable in any practical sense

if someone wants to posit a solution, here's some unit test cases:

- unit test 1:

  - the base set is all integers between -1,000,000,000,000 and +1,000,000,000,000 except for 100,000,000,000 randomly-removed values
  - the input set is 100,000,000,000 randomly-generated integers in the same range
- unit test 2:

  - the base set is the Fibonacci series
  - the input set is 1T randomly-generated integers in the range 0..infinity

Comment: added some pragmatic notes to address your points. (even qsort will fail if the list so large as to run out of stack space)

Comment: For unit test 1 it would be more efficient to handle the complement of the base set.

Comment: @[Jason S]: true, but given the problem description ("Nothing in particular is known now about the range or the set to be tested") you would have no way of knowing that!

Comment: You wouldn't know that at design time, but you would know that at run-time, since the algorithm is aware of the fixed set of inputs it's given, & could count to see if the set or its complement is larger/simpler/whatever.

Comment: so your solution is a set of heuristics guessing at which special-case optimizations to apply; can implement as the strategy pattern for code generation, that would work - but since the problem is open ended, you would have an unbounded set of possible heuristics

Answer (score 1):

there's also [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), not sure how it scales for time, or in space with respect to distribution of original numbers. (e.g. if the bits are stored in chunks of 8/16/32/64, then sparse bitsets are inefficient)

or perhaps [this (compressed bit set)](http://code.google.com/p/compressedbitset/) or [this (bit vector)](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/memsave.html) webpage (I googled for "large sparse bit sets" and "compressed bit sets")

Comment: Interesting. However I suspect that the compressed bit set thing is not tuned for accessing individual bits. Some sort of random access compression system would be needed (but that seems to be an active field of R&D)