# match word if not inside other word

Tags: regex

`thecompletestring` must match `complete`
`thecompletelystring` must not match `complete`
`theuncompletestring` must not match `complete`
`theuncompletelystring` must not match `complete`

I tried word boundaries, but they don't work in URLs.

I have a word list in an array, one word, one item.

How to match a word if it isn't inside an other word?

Comment: Are all dictionary words possible in your url, or do you have a limited set of words to choose from?

Comment: any en-US word can be in the URL

Comment: Not only can you not do this with regexps, but I have attended research presentations on the topic of parsing Sanskit, which is difficult precisely because apparently it is written without spaces. That was using grammar to disambiguate word limits, though, perhaps more than what you want to do.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405433/compression-algorithm-for-encoding-word-lists for affix and suffix analysis

Answer (score 4):

This cannot be done with regexp. To successfully distinguish between those cases, you need to write something that understands the English language. That will obviously not be easy to do properly.

To get pretty close, you could use a dictionary of words and see if the string can be split to words in that dictionary with the word you're looking for as one of the words. This will not account for typos or misunderstandings or two words accidentally being considered as one. You would need something that truly speaks a human language for that.